# Getting first root of a leaf in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have follwing simple graph:

```
CREATE (:leaf)<-[:rel]-(:nonleaf)<-[:rel]-(:nonleaf)<-[:rel]-(:nonleaf)<-[:rel]-(r1:nonleaf{root:true})<-[:rel]-(r2:nonleaf{root:true})
```

I want to get the first ancestor starting from `(:leaf)` with `root:true` set on it. That is I want to get `r1`. For this I wrote following cypher:

```
MATCH (:leaf)<-[*]-(m)<-[*]-(r:nonleaf{root:true}) WHERE m.root<>true OR NOT exists(m.root) 
RETURN r
```

But it returned both `(r1)` and `(r2)`. Same happened for following cypher:

```
MATCH shortestPath((l:leaf)<-[*]-(r:nonleaf{root:true}))
RETURN r
```

Whats going on here?

**Update**
Ok after thinking more, it clicked to my mind that `(r2)` is also returned because on path from `(:leaf)` to `(r2)`, there are nodes with no `root` property set on them (this should have clicked to me earlier, pretty much obvious, subtle interpretation mistake). In other words, it returns `(:nonleaf{root:true})` if **"for at least one `m`"** following condition is true: `m.root<>true OR NOT exists(m.root)`. The requirement here is that the condition should be valid for **"all `m`s"** on the path, **"not at least one `m`"**. Now it remains to figure out how to put this in cypher and my grip on cypher isnt that tight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce that there is a single root node on the matched path with the help of the [`single()`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-single) predicate function:

```
MATCH p=(:leaf)<-[*]-(r:nonleaf{root:true})
WHERE SINGLE(m IN nodes(p) WHERE exists(m.root) AND m.root=true )
RETURN r
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to adjust your where condition a little so that it says "and the `:nonleaf` node before the root `:nonleaf` node matched is not itself marked as a root node".  I think this will satisfy your needs.

```
MATCH (l:leaf)<-[*]-(r:nonleaf {root: true})
WHERE NOT (:nonleaf {root: true})<--(r)
RETURN r
```

**UPDATED**

Reading the updated example in the comments, I thought of another way to solve your problem using the APOC procedure `apoc.path.expandConfig`.

It does require a slight change to your data. Each `root: true` node should have a `:root` label set on it. Here is an update statement...

```
MATCH (n:nonleaf {root:true})
SET n:root
RETURN n
```

And here is the updated query

```
MATCH (leaf:leaf {name: 'leaf'})
WITH leaf
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(leaf, {relationshipFilter:'<rel',labelFilter:'/root'} ) yield path
RETURN last(nodes(path))
```

Comment: I guess this will fail for: `CREATE (:leaf)<-[:rel]-(:nonleaf)<-[:rel]-(:nonleaf)<-[:rel]-(:nonleaf)<-[:rel]-(r1:nonleaf{root:true})<-[:rel]-(:nonleaf)<-[:rel]-(r2:nonleaf{root:true})`. It will return both `(r1)` and `(r2)`. Right?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. It seems that you assumed that following will not happen: `(nonroot)<-(root)<-(nonroot)<-(root)`. In this case, both roots will be returned, but I need only leftmost root. Thats what I put in comments with new `CREATE`. Try these: `CREATE (:leaf {id:'leaf1'})<-[:rel]-(:nonleaf)<-[:rel]-(:nonleaf)<-[:rel]-(:nonleaf)<-[:rel]-(r1:nonleaf{root:true})<-[:rel]-(:nonleaf)<-[:rel]-(r2:nonleaf{root:true})` and `MATCH (l:leaf {id: 'leaf1'})<-[*]-(r:nonleaf {root: true}) WHERE NOT (:nonleaf {root: true})<--(r) RETURN r`. Anyways Leon's answer seems to be precise.

Comment: @Mahesha999 Yes, I tried my queries from the very beginning on the modified graph (with a non-root node added between the root nodes)

Comment: @mahesh - I supplied an alternate approach to solving your problem that I think meets your needs this time. :)